# Home made table saw + home made scoring blade

Tags: table-saw

Can angle grinder be used as motor for scoring blade? What I have found so far the rotation speed should be pretty similar and regular scoring blade can be probably also fitted on the grinder.

Comment: I'm not sure what info you found but angle grinders as far as I know will usually have a *much* higher rotational speed than a typical table saw, possibly three times higher.

Comment: [Scoring blade](http://www.grizzly.com/products/12-Sliding-Table-Saw-with-Scoring-Blade-Motor/G0699?utm_campaign=zPage&utm_source=grizzly.com) at 8000rpm vs. [Angle grinder](http://m.homedepot.com/p/DEWALT-13-Amp-7-in-8-000-RPM-Medium-Angle-Grinder-DW840/203070242) at 8000rpm. Where is the difference. Im talking about scoring blade not main blade

Comment: 8,000 RPM would be very high for a table saw, typical speeds are 4,000 *and lower*. By comparison the speeds quoted for angle grinders (in Europe at least) are often in excess of 10,000 RPM.

Comment: I know it used to be fairly common to homebrew table saws before safer commercially made saws were  widely available at reasonable prices -- but given that a table saw is potentially one of the most dangerous tools in the shop, I really have to question the wisdom of attempting this at all, never mind trying to add something that needs fairly precise alignment.

Comment: Given fairly steady home made saw(used for couple years), which I want only to enhance with scoring ability for laminated boards. The scoring blade is dived only milimeters or so, which diminishes the need for ulimately precise alignment(It actualy only breaks the lamination layer)

Comment: If you mount it in a way that you can adequately adjust the alignment and depth of cut, it seems like it would work fine--after all, it will be a 4" or smaller blade instead of a 10" blade, so a higher RPM makes sense. Are there any specific concerns you have?

Comment: Looking for any DIYer that did that an still is able to type.

Comment: Apparently there are no such DIYers :).